# How to make sure expo knows SDK is installed in my laptop

Tags: sdk, react-native, expo

I am currently making a `react native` app and have installed `expo` but I am getting the error below in the image. I have SDK(29) in my device but how do I make sure that `expo` knows it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have made `Expo` a project.
Did you ran `react-native init` ???  If yes, it is not an `Expo` project. it is only `react-native` project

> To make sure that `Expo` is installed properly: Verify that the
>   installation was successful by running `expo whoami`.

If you want an `Expo` project, run the following command.

```
expo init AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
npm start # you can also use: expo start
```

---

The project you received from `Git` seems to be a `React-native` project.
You can try this command.

```
cd gitproject
npm install
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
npx react-native run-ios or run-android
```

Comment: Actually I have cloned the project from github so can't do init project. Any other alternative?

Comment: running expo whoami is giving not logged in. what does that mean?

Comment: @joedenly  I modified my answer.

Comment: @joedenly You're not logged in yet, so you will see "Not logged in".

Comment: I am currently running npm install(will take some time) but what does cd ios and pod install means ?

Comment: @joedenly The reason why you run the 'pod install' command in the iOS folder is the dependency setting part of iOS.

Comment: can you please tell me what does npx react-native run-android do

Comment: @joedenly `run-ios` is running Ios Simulator and `run-android` is running Android Simulator

Comment: I have accepted your answer but can you please tell me how can I run this app using expo

Comment: @joedenly React-native projects cannot be run on Expo. Because the Expo project does not have an iOS folder and an Android folder. If you want to run as an Expo, you need to bring in an Expo project from Github and run it.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal run

```
expo --version
```

if installed it will return the version like

```
5.2.0
```

else you will get

```
'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```